# WPF C# Button Style with custom appearance and Storyboards

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, controltemplate

I have two questions:

1. I´d like to create a Button, where the Border appears counterclockwise on MouseEnter and disappears clockwise on MouseLeave. 
   The Background of the Button is transparent while on IsMouseOver, IsPressed and IsDefault mode. Now I want to get this into a Dynamic Resource Style, so I don´t have to create like a hundred Rectangles within the Button section.
   This is what I have got so far for the hardcoded part:

   Main

and this for the Style part:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonNavBarPages" TargetType="Button">

            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF494949"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri Light" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

2. I also have the idea of creating a Button, which sets the Background on IsMouseOver to LightGray, but also the Foreground to White. Everything I tried so far doesn´t work out...

I am really looking forward to your answers!